# Error in UITableViewDelegate in separate class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to separate `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` in another class for reducing and changing delegate in `UITableView`

This my code
**GroupTableController.h**

```
@interface GroupTableController : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

  {
     OutlayGroupsCollection *outlayGroupsCollection;
     Car *currentCar;
     Period *currentPeriod;
  }

-(void) setCar:(Car*) currentCar andPeriod:(Period*) currentPeriod;
-(int) total;
@end
```

**GroupTableController.m**

```
@implementation GroupTableController

-(void) setCar:(Car*) car andPeriod:(Period*) period
{
  currentCar = car;
  currentPeriod = period;
}

-(int) total
{
  if(outlayGroupsCollection == nil){
            outlayGroupsCollection = [OutlayGroupsCollection new];
        }

    NSMutableArray *list = [outlayGroupsCollection list:currentCar     forPeriod:currentPeriod];
    int result = 0;
    for (OutlayGroup *group in list) {
        result=result+group.sum;
    }
return result;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    OutlayGroupCell *cell = (OutlayGroupCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OutlayGroupCell"];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[OutlayGroupCell alloc] init];
    }

    OutlayGroup *group = [[outlayGroupsCollection list:currentCar forPeriod:currentPeriod ] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.typeView.text = [OutlayType getName:[group type]];
    cell.sumView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [group sum]];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if(outlayGroupsCollection==nil){
        outlayGroupsCollection = [OutlayGroupsCollection new];
    }
    return [[outlayGroupsCollection list:currentCar forPeriod:currentPeriod ] count];
}


@end
```

And I bound this by next:

```
GroupTableController *gtd = [[GroupTableController alloc] init];

mainTableView.delegate = gtd;
mainTableView.dataSource = gtd;
[(GroupTableController*)mainTableView.delegate setCar: currentCar andPeriod: currentPeriod];
```

But, I got error

```
[GroupTableController numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x9e4d640
```

What I do wrong!?
(I am new in Objective C!)

Comment: Can you show the whole method were you initialise `gtd`. You need to keep a strong reference to `gtd` somewhere, because your using ARC, and  `tableView`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` are weak references, it deallocates `gtd` at the end of the method.

Comment: Yes! You are right! Strong reference had solved my problem! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `delegate` and `dataSource` property types of `UITableView` are `assign`, which means that they won't retain `gtd` for you.

You need to make sure that after you create the controller (`gtd`) you then retain it as a property.

Comment: Yes, I set "gtd" like "@property (strong, nonatomic) GroupTableController  *groupTableController;" and this solve my problem.